# What's the difference of source complile or use apt?

Tags: apt

For example， I want to install `glog`, I could use

`sudo apt-get install libgoogle-glog-dev`

or

```
git clone https://github.com/google/glog

./autogen.sh && ./configure && make && make install
```

What's the difference?

I'll appreciate it if you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

`sudo apt-get install libgoogle-glog-dev`,

It installs and maintains programs and other collections of files (data, documentation, etc.) in the form of packages.

while in second one you first download the source from Github repository and then run various shell files which get it installed on your system.

I hope it helps you.